# How to use wt to show output when targeting wsl2 with vs2022?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've set up CMakePresets.json and able to run code both in **Local Machine** and **WSL: Ubuntu.**

But the default output window for wsl2 targets is **Linux Console Window**, which is different from a external wt window with targets in **Local Machine**. Besides, sometimes **Linux Console window** fails to pop up after building.

So is there any way I can set wt to be the output window for targets in WSL2?

Comment: What is "wt"? How do you actually "build"? If the WSL terminal "fails to pop up" what has happened with the build?

Comment: wt is Windows Terminal. I'm using Windows 11 and everything that has a external console is using Windows Terminal e.g. vs output in Local Machine. So I wish to use external console(wt) rather than Linux Console Window. Nothing wrong with the build, the Linux Console window not popping up after **Run without Debugging** and the output remains the same as last build. I have to **Start Debugging** to update the output.